# Svelte Simple form with file upload not working

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I'm using `svelte` and `svelte-forms-lib`. I've got a form component that looks like:

```
<script>

    import { createForm } from "svelte-forms-lib";

    export let mode;
    export let submitFn;
    export let formData = {};

    let fileInput = "";
    let imagePreview = "";

    const handleDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        const file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
        handleImage(file)
    }

    const handleImage = imageFile => {
        if (imageFile) {
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile)
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = readerEvent => {
                formData.image = readerEvent.target.result;
            }
            imagePreview = fileURL;
        }
    }

    const clearImagePreview = () => {
        imagePreview = "";
        formData.image = "";
    }

    const { form, handleChange, handleSubmit } = createForm({
        initialValues: formData,
        onSubmit: async data => {
            console.log("submitting form")
            console.log(data)
        }
    })

</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit} enctype="multipart/form-data">
{#if imagePreview === ""}
                        <label for="dropzone-file" class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full h-64 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed cursor-pointer dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600">
                            <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center pt-5 pb-6" on:drop={handleDrop} ondragover="return false">
                                <svg aria-hidden="true" class="mb-3 w-10 h-10 text-gray-400" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M7 16a4 4 0 01-.88-7.903A5 5 0 1115.9 6L16 6a5 5 0 011 9.9M15 13l-3-3m0 0l-3 3m3-3v12"></path></svg>
                                <p class="mb-2 text-sm text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400"><span class="font-semibold">Click to upload</span> or drag and drop</p>
                                <p class="text-xs text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">SVG, PNG, JPG or GIF (MAX. 800x400px)</p>
                            </div>
                            <input
                                    id="dropzone-file"
                                    bind:files={formData.image}
                                    name="image"
                                    on:change={ e => handleImage(e.target.files[0])}
                                    type="file"
                                    class="hidden" />
                        </label>

                    {:else}
                        <img src={imagePreview}
                             class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center w-full h-64 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed dark:hover:bg-bray-800 dark:bg-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:border-gray-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600" />
                        <a href="#" on:click={clearImagePreview}>Remove</a>
                    {/if}

<div class="grid grid-cols-1">
                <div class="p-4  flex item-center justify-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-active btn-primary">
                        { mode == "new" ? "Save" : "Update" }
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

</form>
```

When I click the `Save` button, I don't see the data for my image in the object. Basically I've identified 2 issues:

1. `reader.onload` doesn't seem to be fired. If I add logs within `reader.onload` they never appear on the console.
2. If I run a method from the `reader`, let's say `reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile)`:

```
const handleImage = imageFile => {

        if (imageFile) {
            const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageFile)
            const reader = new FileReader();
            const dataAsURL = reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);

            reader.onload = readerEvent => {
                console.log("here in reader.onload")
                formData.image = readerEvent.target.result;
                console.log("reader event...");
                console.log(formData.image);
            }
            imagePreview = fileURL;
        }
```

I do see the logs from `reader.onload`. Furthermore, I can see that `formData.image` is being populated with the base64 representation of the image BUT when I click the submit button the `formData` object does not have the `image` property.

For simplicity I've omitted all other fields in the form, most of them of type text, but they do appear when the form is submitted. For instance:

```
<input
                                id="barcode"
                                bind:value={formData.barcode}
                                on:change={handleChange}
                                type="text"
                                class="input w-full py-4 font-medium bg-gray-100 border-gray-200 text-sm
                  focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-400 focus:bg-white"
                        />
```

is being submitted.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the form, the library will make a deep copy of the `initialValue` [[code]](https://github.com/tjinauyeung/svelte-forms-lib/blob/7df1b1df4f02c5ff512e2542c879056ac2d8138d/lib/create-form.js#L33)
So changing `formData` doesn't have any effect on `data` in `onSubmit`.

If you look at the documentation the values of the input fields are bind to a `$form` store which is destructured from `createForm`

```
bind:value={$form.title}
```

Your other input elements don't work because of the value binding to `formData` but because of the `on:change={handleChange}` that does update `$form` as well.

To make your example work I'd

- change to `bind:files={$form.imgFiles}`
- remove the `on:change` on the file input
- read the file inside `onSubmit`
- display the preview Image via a reactive variable
  `$: previewImgSrc = $form.imgFiles ? URL.createObjectURL($form.imgFiles[0]) : ''`

Comment: Your suggestions worked. Thanks a lot. Don't know if its just me but `svelte-forms-lib` is not clear enough (too little details). Anyway, this works. Also, I'm still just getting used to reactive variables so this was a great example on a real case scenario. Thanks again

Comment: This approach is working perfectly well.. removed the on:change directive and adding the bind:files directive seems to work.